# Razor html label doesn't get ID when value is empty

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `Html.Label` in my MVC razor project which looks like :

```
@Html.Label("No Match", new { id = "RegExMatchResult" })
```

It works fine when I put `"No Match"` and my jquery can find it using the `ID ="RegExMatchResult"`.

However, when I change the value into an empty string:

```
@Html.Label("", new { id = "RegExMatchResult" })
```

JQuery can't find the label using `ID ="RegExMatchResult"`. I have tested both ways and check the page source and it corresponds to what I said above (no ID when value is empty)...

Does anyone know why it does that and what I solution for this?

Comment: Can you show an example of `However, when I change the value into an empty string ("")` .   I'm not following what you mean.

Comment: Why not just use a HTML label? (`<label id="RegExMatchResult"></label>`/`<label id="RegExMatchResult">No Match</label>`) The MVC helpers appear to be adding no benefit here.

Comment: @Liam that worked perfectly... Do you know why `@Html.Label("", new { id = "RegExMatchResult" })` don't work?

Comment: Not really, there is nothing in the docs that suggest this functionality. I would guess (*though as I said the docs don't support this*), that it does not render an empty label.

Comment: I've just checked it myself, and yes, for some reason **MVC does not render anything if you pass an empty string to `Html.Label`**, i.e. `@Html.Label("")` renders nothing, not even an empty label...not sure if this is by design but the docs don't mention this functionality.

Comment: Interesting... I'll stick with the HTML label for now... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LabelExtensions.cs), your `@Html.Label("", new { id = "RegExMatchResult" })` will match this method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
     return Label(html, expression, labelText: null, htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes, metadataProvider: null);
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
internal static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
{
       return Label(html,
                    expression,
                    labelText,
                    HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes),
                    metadataProvider);
 }
```

Then here:

```
internal static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression, string labelText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
{
      return LabelHelper(html,
                         ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(expression, html.ViewData, metadataProvider),
                         expression,
                         labelText,
                         htmlAttributes);
}
```

And finally here where you will see that since you passed an empty string in it will return a `MvcHtmlString.Empty;` and thus not render any html in the browser. Since it is not rendered your jquery will not find it.

```
internal static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName, string labelText = null, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
{
      string resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText))
      {
           return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
      }

      TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
      tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
      tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
      tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes, replaceExisting: true);
      return tag.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly old question but still appears a lot.

You can add a space, which will force the label to render.

```
@Html.Label("lbErrorMessage", " ", new { @id = "lbErrorMessage", @class = "message-sub-footer-error" })
```

So in your case:

```
@Html.Label("RegExMatchResult", ***" "***, new { id = "RegExMatchResult" })
```

instead of this:

```
@Html.Label("RegExMatchResult", ***""***, new { id = "RegExMatchResult" })
```

Comment: Adding a space in empty string helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can pretty much assume that the reason nothing is rendered is because MVC is simply following HTML standards in this scenario because a label must be associated with a form control.

Given that you're saying that you're giving a blank association property, then you don't need a label because you're not associating it with a form control. I really don't think you should be using a label if you're not intending to link it to a form control, consider using a `span` or something else in it's place.

By replacing the html helper call with a HTML `label`, you're esentially breaking the standards yourself because MVC won't do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The html.label can be a blank error label.
The reason you want to render it to the page initially could be for spacing considerations.
You can then later use the label in code behind to place a message into the view.
You do not need to use LabelFor to link the control to a form. If you use the Label element within a form tag then essentially it is linked and accessible via code.

So I my answer as correct.

Thanks,
Graham